# /loot giving "An unexpected error occurred trying to execute that command"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm attempting to use `/loot` to give myself fishing loot, which should be fairly easy. I'm using this command;

```
/loot give EarthToAccess fish minecraft:gameplay/fishing/treasure -78 65 -212 mainhand
```

...however, it throws me the error `An unexpected error occurred trying to execute that command.` I tried to remove `mainhand` since the argument for it is optional anyway, but it still returns the same error. As far as I can tell, the syntax is correct; I'm supposedly giving myself the treasure loot table from the coordinates listed. Is there some bug with `/loot give` right now?

Answer (score -1):

This worked fine for me:

`/loot give [yourPlayerName] fish minecraft:gameplay/fishing/treasure ~ ~ ~`

Using `~ ~ ~` for the location argument will give it to your current location.

Could any mods you're using be causing a problem?

Comment: ... or datapacks or it's just a copy-paste mistake.

Comment: Nope. This is an unmodded version. I tried it both with coordinates and with relative coordinates, but no dice. I'm on 20w15a, but this issue has persisted for a while, actually.

Answer (score -1):

Try it in an ocean or a river. If that doesn't work, it could be that the command is just broken.

I'd recommend submitting a bug report of it to Mojang.